# radio input checked after click on input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i got simple form what contain radio input and text input.
My goal is: check radio input when click on text input

Thanks

```
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <label for="gr_1_option_4">
         <input type="radio" id="gr_1_option_4" name="group1" value=""> 
                 Sonstiges: 
          <input type="text" id="gr_1_option_4" name="group1"/>
     </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You should never have multiple elements with the same ID, ID's shall always be unique

Comment: You can use jQuery to do this.

Comment: You have two validity issues here, the first (already stated) is the duplicate `id`, the second is that you can't have two `<input>` elements inside the same `<label>`.

Answer (score 6):

You should have unique `id` for the `input` and `radio` then you can associate a click event in `input` by its `id` that will check radio input when click.

**using jQuery**

```js
$('#gr_1_input_4').click(function(){
  $('#gr_1_option_4').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <label for="gr_1_option_4">
         <input type="radio" id="gr_1_option_4" name="group1" value=""> 
                 Sonstiges: 
          <input type="text" id="gr_1_input_4" name="group1"/>
     </label>
</div>
```

**using JavaScript**

```js
document.getElementById('gr_1_input_4').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById("gr_1_option_4").checked = true;
});
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <label for="gr_1_option_4">
         <input type="radio" id="gr_1_option_4" name="group1" value=""> 
                 Sonstiges: 
          <input type="text" id="gr_1_input_4" name="group1"/>
     </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have `focus` event handler for input text and inside it set `checked` property of the radio button.

**NOTE**: Don't use same id for multiple html elements as it will end up with javascript / jquery not working for id oriented code. You have used `gr_1_option_4` as id for both radio and text input.

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[type=text][name=group1]").on("focus", function(){
       $("input[type=radio][name=group1]").prop("checked", true);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <label for="gr_1_option_4">
         <input type="radio" id="gr_1_option_4" name="group1" value=""> 
                 Sonstiges: 
          <input type="text" id="gr_1_option_4" name="group1"/>
     </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change your Element's Id , you cant have same ids among elements.

Secondly you can add an event handler like

```
document.getElementById("textId").onclick = function() {myFunction()};
```

and define that function like

```
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("radioButtonID").checked = true;
}
```

EDIT: I FILL THE ANSWER AND SEE THAT ALREADY SOMEONE HAD ASNWERED but i keep my answer because is not Jquery like the other

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way is using `prev` .

```js
$('input[type="text"]').click(function(){
  $(this).prev('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <label for="gr_1_option_4">
         <input type="radio" id="gr_1_option_4" name="group1" value=""> 
                 Sonstiges: 
          <input type="text" id="gr_1_input_4" name="group1"/>
     </label>
</div>
```